# How to recover git repositories

Tags: git, gitlab, gitolite

Somehow my local git server stopped working. Whenever i tried to clone/push/pull getting below error.

```
$ git pull origin
FATAL: parse './conf/gitolite.conf-compiled.pm' failed: No such file or directory
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But the required `gitolite.conf-compiled.pm` file exists

```
/home/git/.gitolite/conf/gitolite.conf
/home/git/.gitolite/conf/gitolite.conf-compiled.pm
/home/git/.gitolite/conf/rule_info
```

So, now the question is how do i get all the repositories code. When i navigate to one of the repository and the directory structure is like below

```
root@INLT-TRE0012:/home/git/repositories/cl.git# ls
branches  config  description  gl-conf  gl-slave-tregit1.status  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs
```

Comment: This is a Gitolite issue, not a Git issue (Git does not include Gitolite, Gitolite is strictly an add-on). I have not used Gitolite since about 2010 but this seems particularly odd since one runs Gitolite on the *server* (`git fetch`, which `git pull` runs, runs on the *client*) and hence the `FATAL: parse ...` text should be prefixed with `remote: `. The missing file would then be missing on the *server itself*.

Answer (score 1):

Check your version of Gitolite.

[This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitolite/bgHU9XwxW6A) points to [commit 35e0b2a](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/35e0b2a9c967005fd7ecb6708388a88ccb85844e):

> If the output of '`perl -V`' does not end with a sole "`.`" as the last
>   line, your perl is [ahead of current released perl](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Flists.debian.org%2Fdebian-devel-announce%2F2016%2F08%2Fmsg00013.html&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEHA7ChZakZBn6NoObNon0ozAvmlw).
>
> I just pushed a update (commit 35e0b2a) which should fix it.
>
> ### prep for perl 5.26 removing "`.`" from `@inc`
>
> Someone on irc found that debian has already implemented it, so gitolite fails.
>
> This fix is useful even on older perls.

Answer (score 0):

> *So, now the question is how do i get all the repositories code. When i navigate to one of the repository and the directory structure is like below*
>
> ```
> root@INLT-TRE0012:/home/git/repositories/cl.git# ls
> branches  config  description  gl-conf  gl-slave-tregit1.status  HEAD
> ```

This is a "bare clone". It is just the Git repository/history with no checked out files. In a normal clone those files are in the `.git` directory. Bare clones are there to only be pushed to and pulled from.

You can get a normal clone with checked out files from this directory just like you would from a URL.

```
git clone /home/git/repositories/cl.git
```